# Expand parent menu if child menu is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have a menu with sub child menus. The problem I am facing is that whenever I select a child menu after page loads, the menu collapses. I want to open the parent menu expanded.

**The HTML Code is:**

---

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='http://internallink.com/home'><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class='active has-sub'><a href='http://internallink.com/products'><span>Products</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='http://internallink.com/product1'><span>Product 1</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='http://internallink.com/subProduct'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                            <li class='last'><a href='http://internallink.com/subProduct'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class='has-sub'><a href='http://internallink.com/product2'><span>Product 2</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='http://internallink.com/subProduct'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                            <li class='last'><a href='http://internallink.com/subProduct'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='http://internallink.com/about'><span>About</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='http://internallink.com/contact'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**The JS is:**

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#cssmenu').on("click","li.has-sub .holder",function () {
        var element = jQuery(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });

    jQuery('#cssmenu ul li.has-sub').prepend('<span class="holder"></span>');

});
```

How can i expand the parent menu if child menu is selected.

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/x415mjfq/

Comment: What's the problem? I can expand the menus all the way: http://i.imgur.com/lvPLtnJ.png

Comment: @Hatchet that is not the problem. He wants to persist the open menu on page load when you navigate to a child page. Which really can't be demoed in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You have the full, absolute URL's in the links; that can be used to your advantage. Simply use `document.querySelector` with the square bracket selector, and the `location.href` property:

```
document.querySelector("a[href='" + location.href + "']").classList.add("selected");
```

Then, do whatever you need to do to it. In this example, I'm adding the `selected` class.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/2rbhu327/)

Comment: Can you tell me where excatly should i place this link in my js ?

Comment: This is just an example. You'll need to edit it yourself before putting it on your website. You'll need to add the proper CSS, and change the JavaScript to fit your needs. Right now, it just selects the `a` tag. You can traverse the DOM and select and style any element you need from there.

Comment: You have to define the `selected` class in your CSS first. It also won't work in the fiddle, if you're using your own URLs.