# Make menu parent expand if child is currently active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm currently attempting to make a menu which is expandable when clicked, stays open, until a child is clicked, then user should be taken to that page, and the menu should still be expanded when that site is reached. (currently it collapses).

I have currently got the part down where i have a menu that expands and show childs when clicked. It's currently made in javascript. I'm making the menu with wordpress, and wordpress automatically adds class "current-menu-item" to the li which is being visited (if that helps).

```js
var clickMenu = function() {
 var getEls = document.getElementById("menu-shopmenu").getElementsByTagName("LI");
 var getAgn = getEls;

 for (var i=0; i<getEls.length; i++) {
   getEls[i].onclick=function() {
    for (var x=0; x<getAgn.length; x++) {
    getAgn[x].className=getAgn[x].className.replace("unclick", "");
    getAgn[x].className=getAgn[x].className.replace("click", "unclick");
    }
   if ((this.className.indexOf('unclick'))!=-1) {
    this.className=this.className.replace("unclick", "");;
    }
    else {
    this.className+=" click";
    }
   }
   getEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
    this.className+=" hover";
   }
   getEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
    this.className=this.className.replace("hover", "");
   }
  }
 }
 
window.addEventListener("load", clickMenu);
```

Now I'm just looking for help making it stay expanded once new page is loaded.

Also, will these two functions make a conflict in the design?

Comment: Hello again, i tried  your method again after i checked the syntax in your reference, now it works.

But there are some new issues that follow. If i in  the future should have a sub category A under two different parent categories, then they would both be expanded. 

Also, since its a webshop im working on, i would like the menu to be expanded while im viewing a product.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check 'parent' of `current-menu-item` element. And apply `display:block` or any other css which makes menu element visible.
check below code if it meets your requirements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".current-menu-item").parent("your_parent_ul_div").css("display": "block");
});
```

ref-https://api.jquery.com/parent/

---

ref->[Expand parent menu if child menu is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070031/expand-parent-menu-if-child-menu-is-selected?rq=1)

ref->https://webdesignerhut.com/active-class-navigation-menu/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Here is a link to the menu im trying to create, i thought you would like to see the html. Dont mind the mess :)

http://web14.simo9928.iba-abakomp.dk/wordpress/produkt-kategori/fiskegrej/endegrej/spinnere/

I tried your example without luck.

Currently trying this:

$(document).ready(function(){
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
 $(".sub-menu li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});

 Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where i have  added active { display: block !important; } to the css